# android location manager minTime vs minDistance

Tags: android, locationmanager

I wrote a simple locationManager and locationListener using:

```
        GPS_distance = 30;
        GPS_interval = 2000;
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(GPS_provider, GPS_interval, GPS_distance, locationListener);
```

So onLocationChanged 'should' be updated EITHER every 2 seconds, OR on a 30 meter distance change.  What is happening is the location gets updated ONLY in 30 meters.  If I set distance to 0, then the time interval works!

Debugging on a Samsung Galaxy S4.

Comment: Read the [documentation:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates)

Answer (score 6):

By looking at the Docs,
it says that there is an AND condition between the two.

> location provider will only send your application an update when the location has changed by at least minDistance meters, AND at least minTime milliseconds have passed

That means that you have to pass the minDistance you have set and and amount of time.

Check the Docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).